# Why do i get a value error using pandas and xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to make a script that uses pandas to read some values from a row in Excel, loop an action for each value in the row and feed some of that info into a new Excel document. I am using the interrows command in pandas to loop through the values in the row.

Error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I understand that pandas and if statements don't work well together, and you end up getting this error. I don't have any if statements. I am pretty new to python and don't get why I get this error.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'C:Users\user\output.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\user\input.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['AlarmID'])

row = 0
col = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    worksheet.write(row, col, "text")
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Can I ask why there is the letter "r" before the file paths?

Comment: This means the string is interpreted literally for the path

Comment: Oh thanks! So you don't have to change backslashes to forward slashes! I never knew that, cheers!

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce the error you have, the intended use of the worksheet.write() method is to have (row_index, col_index, value). Therefore passing row to this function from df.iterrows() will not work. You can read the examples here https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is coming from double calling the variable "row". Once as the thing in the for loop and then again in the write statement. Try something like this:

```
row = 0
col = 0

for item in df.iterrows():
    worksheet.write(row,col, "text")
    row+=1   
workbook.close()
```